# Use of uninitialized value in print

Tags: perl

Please check this code. Getting Error

```
"Use of uninitialized value in print at 2.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1."
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %questions = (
    1 => "Java",
    2 => "Python",
    3 => "Perl",
    4 => "C"
);
print "Enter a number between 1 and 4:";
my $selection = <STDIN>;
print $questions{$selection};
```

Comment: Usually if your interpreter/compiler says that there's an error, then there is an error. Did you need something else?

Comment: You might also want to cover the case where a user enters something other than 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: You might be interested in using `use strict` as well as `use warnings`. It will prevent you from making hard to find mistakes.

Comment: Your code isn't even 13 lines long! Don't run one piece of code and post another!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the newline when reading from STDIN:

```
chomp(my $selection = <STDIN>);
```

The reason is that hash keys are unique and must be entered exactly. `1\n` is considered a different key than `1`.

Note that if you had used an array (since you use numbers anyway), you would not have had this problem, because `1\n` would be converted to a number silently.

You might want to enter a sanity check, if for nothing else, so that you can catch errors like this:

```
print "You entered: '$selection'\n";
if (not defined $questions{$selection}) {
    print "That is not a valid option\n";
}
```

In this case, you would have gotten the output:

```
You entered '1
'
That is not a valid option
```

(Note the embedded newline in the single quoted string)

For future debugging, you might be interested in learning about `Data::Dumper`, a core module, which is a simple way to print your variables to show you what is inside them:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \@foo;   # print reference to array
print Dumper $foo;    # print scalar
```

This gives output like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'foo',
          2,
          3
        ];
$VAR1 = 'foo';
```

And the `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` option is nice for showing hidden whitespace. In your case, it would have printed the newline out for you:

```
$VAR1 = "1\n";
```

Comment: The user may also have entered something completely different - the code only accounts for the user entering 1 - 4.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Indeed. But then he presumably would be aware of that, and would not ask this question. Without `chomp`, he cannot print any hash element at all.

Comment: @ialarmedalien But good point about adding error checking, I added that.

Comment: @TLP Adding error checking is one of the most important things for new programmers to learn (IMO). Nice answer and explanation. `:)`

Comment: @ialarmedalien Indeed. Thank you. Using `Data::Dumper` with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1` is a very useful method of finding misplaced whitespace like this.